# Qtranslate Custom Font Per Language issue

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, qtranslate

I am facing an issue with a wordpress website for a client who wants to set a custom font-family per each language

i am using Qtranslate plugin for wordpress to translate the content and i managed to this successfully ... i also use a plugin called Custom CSS for wordpress to apply CSS changes in the code

Problem is when i set the custom font using the code .. it sets the custom font for both language .. so kindly help me to fix this

My Custom CSS Code is

```
@font-face {
font-family: GEDinarOne-Medium; 
src: url('http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/fonts/GEDinarOne-Medium.ttf'); 
font-weight: normal;}

:lang(ar) body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, li, a{
    font-family: GEDinarOne-Medium !important; 
  }
```

Comment: Best way to do this is to use WP Hook to select the proper font at WP head.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **create** a `CSS` class and **place it at the bottom** of your `CSS` and then add it to the ***translated content tags.***

For example;

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Yrsa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Yrsa'), local('Yrsa-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/yrsa/v1/HvXbkSMs7hgg2r-HiCNOmA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Indie Flower'), local('IndieFlower'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v8/10JVD_humAd5zP2yrFqw6ugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
body {
  background: #111;
  color: #999;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 10%
}
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
li,
a {
  font-family: 'Yrsa';
}
.otherlanguage {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a Header 1 in font A</h1>
    <h1 class="otherlanguage">This is a Header 1 in font B</h1>
    <h2>This is a Header 2 in font A</h2>
    <h2 class="otherlanguage">This is a Header 2 in font B</h2>
    <h3>This is a Header 2 in font A</h3>
    <h3 class="otherlanguage">This is a Header 2 in font B</h3>
    <p>This is a paragraph using font A
      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in eam simul nostrud definiebas, mea iusto placerat prodesset ei. Eum summo audiam ea. Vitae aperiri at duo. Vis atomorum partiendo id, nam ea noluisse platonem. Nec minimum consequat cu, pri in harum moderatius. Ferri
      aperiam forensibus an nam.</p>
    <p class="otherlanguage">This is a paragraph using font B
      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in eam simul nostrud definiebas, mea iusto placerat prodesset ei. Eum summo audiam ea. Vitae aperiri at duo. Vis atomorum partiendo id, nam ea noluisse platonem. Nec minimum consequat cu, pri in harum moderatius. Ferri
      aperiam forensibus an nam.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

**Edit: New snippet**

I am sure there is a **better way** to **combine the selectors**, but this should work without changing any HTML.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Yrsa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Yrsa'), local('Yrsa-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/yrsa/v1/HvXbkSMs7hgg2r-HiCNOmA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Indie Flower'), local('IndieFlower'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v8/10JVD_humAd5zP2yrFqw6ugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
.page-id-70 h1,
.page-id-70 h2,
.page-id-70 h3,
.page-id-70 h3,
.page-id-70 h4,
{
  font-family: 'Yrsa';
}
.page-id-71 h1,
.page-id-71 h2,
.page-id-71 h3,
.page-id-71 h3,
.page-id-71 h4,
{
  font-family: 'Indie Flower';
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response .. it is highly appreciated :)                 it will not work out this way .. because i don't have access to the body elements in wordpress .. i use the Custom CSS plugin in order to make any changes

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: No .. it just that i can't access the html structure of each wordpress page

Comment: Another thing you can do is change the font using the page-id in custom CSS
 
I will add another snippet at the bottom of the old one.

Comment: I added the snippet to the same answer. Please note that doing it this way is very tiring. I just wanted to highlight what you can try to investigate.

Comment: Are you using separate urls for different content? You can also use the url as a css selector For example: a, h1, h2, h3, h4, [href="http://example.com/flower/*"] {
   font-family: 'Indie Flower';
} Will change the font for the selected items if the url is /flower or anything under it.